# Accessing global variable defined in C from Asm

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, global-variables, gnu-assembler

I have a C file which contain a global variable foo. How I can access **foo** from another assemby program. 
I am using i586-elf-as (GNU assembler) and i586-elf-gcc (gnu compiler) for building.

Comment: It's unclear whether you really want to access it from another **program** or just from another **module** in the same program. It's also unclear what you tried and what error you got.

Comment: Its another module which is linked with the asm binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the symbol name; `as` treats all undefined symbols as external.

Check compiler output (`gcc -S`) and/or documentation to find out if C variable names get a leading `_` prepended or not.  (`int myglobal` becomes asm `_myglobal` on many non-ELF platforms, but still `myglobal` on Linux/ELF.)

And of course C++ name mangling happens if you use a C++ compiler, except for `extern "C"` variables.

---

If you want to declare it explicitly, there's a `.extern` directive which GAS ignores (for compat with some other Unix assemblers).  [Documentation in the GAS manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Extern.html)

```
.extern foo       # ignored, no extra checking is done because of this
```

---

For example on x86-64, `lea myglobal(%rip), %rsi` or `mov $myglobal, %esi` to get the address into a register in  AT&T syntax.

Or `mov myglobal(%rip), %eax` to load from it.  Or `mov global, %eax` to load from it in 32-bit mode, using a 32-bit absolute address because RIP-relative addressing is only available in 64-bit mode.

Comment: To quote the [manual](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/Extern.html): "`.extern is accepted in the source program—for compatibility with other assemblers—but it is ignored. as treats all undefined symbols as external.`"

Comment: True, but I think it helps add readability, since you know it's being defined elsewhere.

Comment: The point is, it should "just work". If the OP has some problem (which he didn't say) that must be due to something else.

Comment: To access the variable foo do we need to add any special characters like % or $ in instruction?

Comment: No, you don't need anything special. Please post what you tried and what error you get if it doesn't work. The C compiler may however be "mangling" your symbols, adding a leading underscore (`_`) is common.

Comment: I was trying to access the variable with an underscore prefix (undefined reference _foo). Now I'm not getting any error(w/o special characters). thnx